# Definition of set of vectors obtained by a linear combination with bounded coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, polyhedra, polytopes

I am not able to find a definition of a set described by

$V = \{~ \boldsymbol{v} = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \boldsymbol{u}_i,\quad k \lt \infty,\quad 0 \leq \lambda_i \lt +\infty, \quad \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R},\quad \boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{u}_i \in \Bbb R^n ~ \}$

I know it is a polyhedra, more specifically it will be a polytope, but this definition resembles a lot the one of convex hull, just with the different constraints on the coefficients, so I was wandering if it has actually a name.

I need this because I will have to do some calculations on this type of set, and right now i am not able to find anything about it.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: corrected typo in $\lambda_i \leq +\infty$

Comment: It is still just the conical hull. Any real number is finite.

Answer (score 0):

It is called conical hull, as you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination

Comment: I was looking for this, but with bounded coefficients, so not just in R>=0

Comment: What does it mean then in your constraint $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq + \infty$?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a typo

Comment: Then I suggest you to edit your question